# Implement UITouchDown for UIImageView

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4, uiimageview

I know how to implement `touchesBegan` for `UIImageView`

is it possible to implement `UITouchDown` for `UIImageView` ?(i know that i can use `touchesBegan` instead of `UITouchDown` but i want to implement `UITouchDown`)

Comment: By TouchDown, do you mean `UIControlEventTouchDown`?

Comment: yes i mean UIControlEventTouchDown

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Use a UIButton.**

```
UIButton *aButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[aButton setImage:someUIImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[aButton addTarget:self action:@selector(aMethod) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[self.view addSubview:aButton];
```

**Alternative to UIButton (longer method)**

A `UIControl` implements user interactions and support for fine-grained user interactions already. You can combine the functionality of a `UIImageView` and a `UIControl` to achieve this since both are subclasses of `UIView`.

To get this behavior, add an object of UIImageView as a subview to a `UIControl` such that the image is fully covered. Then add a event handler to this control using [`addTarget:action:forControlEvents:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIControl). Here's an example:

```
// assuming the image view object exists
UIImageView *anImageView = ..;

// create a mask that the covers the image exactly
UIControl *mask = [[UIControl alloc] initWithFrame:anImageView.frame];

// add the image as a subview of this mask
CGSize imageSize = anImageView.frame.size;
anImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, imageSize.width, imageSize.height);
[mask addSubview:anImageView];

// add a target-action for the desired control events to this mask
[mask addTarget:self action:@selector(someMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

// add the mask as a subview instead of the image
[self.view addSubview:mask];
```

Comment: Thank you i use longer method

Answer (score 2):

You can use `UITapGestureRecognizer`, instead of creating custom `UIButton`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

control events such as `UIControlEventTouchDown` etc are available for `UIControl's` child objects like `UIButton`, `UITextField` etc. `UIImageView` is a `UIView` and hence cannot generate control notifications.

You have to use `touchesBegan` and co.

Answer (score 0):

control events such as UIControlEventTouchDown etc are available for UIControl's child objects like UIButton, UITextField etc. UIImageView is a UIView and hence cannot generate control notifications.