# Action on image in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios

I am creating a program in which i am adding an image view on the view and i want after clicking on the image only, another detail view should appear.

```
NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:[dic objectForKey:@"img"]]; 
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
[self.view addSubView:imageView];
```

The detail view should appear with the navigation controller. Please help me to solve this problem

Comment: Why don't you use an `UIButton`?

Comment: you mean that on clicking the uiimageview,you need to load some detailView,is it correct scenario?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930449/implement-uitouchdown-for-uiimageview

Comment: You can load an image into UIButton.

Comment: Yes Sarah and thanks to all for reply

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do one thing, add a `UIButton` and set it as custom and add set the image as background of the `UIButton` and then you will be able to click on the same and navigate to other view. Hows that?

Answer (score 3):

You can subclass UIImageView and overwrite the touchesEnded method. This way you can call your UINavigationController and push any other controller when someone touches your UIImageView.

```
@interface YourImageView : UIImageView
{

}
```

in your implementation file you type :

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    // push view controller here or use a delegate 
    // and push the view controller somewhere else
}
```

Make sure you also set the userInteractionEnabled property of your UIImageView to 'YES'

Answer (score 1):

I once had a similar problem and here's the link to the solution: [UIButton inside UIImageView does not respond to taps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6164357/uibutton-inside-uiimageview-does-not-respond-to-taps)

(It's an extension to one of the answers given above...)